# Teamcity and multiple maven dependencies trigger

Tags: java, maven, teamcity

Suppose I have an artifact A. It has snapshot dependency on artifact B. And artifact C has dependencies on both A and B. I have 3 teamcity builds (for A, B, C) with Maven Snapshot dependencies trigger. When I'm building A and when it is deployed, team city triggers builds for artifact B and C. After B is deployed, teamcity triggers C again. So artifact C is build two times. On the one hand this is correct, on the other -- it is excessively.
In the real project there are more dependencies and more unnecessary builds.